# How copy an area from a tikz figure to another figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, spy

I want to copy part of a relatively complex tikz figure (with an image in the background and text above) to another tikz figure on another page.

I'm thinking of using spy, but I haven't found an example of how to copy to another figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to confirm that you can, in principle, use `spy` for that. (Unfortunately your question is a bit vague so I just add a random example from section **73 Spy Library: Magnifying Parts of Pictures** of the  pgfmanual. There are many ways in which one can improve this, but this requires a bit more concrete input from your side, I am afraid.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals,spy} 
\makeatletter
\tikzset{save spy as/.style={execute at end scope={%
\global\setbox#1\copy\tikz@lib@spybox
}}}
\makeatother
\newbox\mybox
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies},
save spy as=\mybox]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\draw [decoration=Koch curve type 1]
decorate { decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (2,0) }}}};
\spy [red] on (1.6,0.3)
in node [left] at (3.5,-1.25);
\spy [blue, size=1cm] on (1,1)
in node [right] at (0,-1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{\usebox\mybox};
\path (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Presumably one could also just use layers.

Comment: Merci, c'est exactement ça!